# Removing white spaces (leading and trailing) from string value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, trim

I have imported a csv file in mongo using mongoimport and I want to remove leading and trailing white spaces from my string value.

Is it possible directly in mongo to use a trim function for all collection or do I need to write a script for that?

My collection contains elements such as:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53857680f7b2eb611e843a32"),
  "category" : "Financial & Legal Services "
}
```

I want to apply trim function for all the collection so that `"category"` should not contain any leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: If you can, just fix the CSV before import.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is not currently possible for an update in MongoDB to refer to the existing value of a current field when applying the update. So you are going to have to loop:

```
db.collection.find({},{ "category": 1 }).forEach(function(doc) {
   doc.category = doc.category.trim();
   db.collection.update(
       { "_id": doc._id },
       { "$set": { "category": doc.category } }
   );
})
```

Noting the use of the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/) operator there and the projected "category" field only in order to reduce network traffic"

You might limit what that processes with a [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) to match:

```
db.collection.find({ 
    "$and": [
        { "category": /^\s+/ },
        { "category": /\s+$/ }
    ]
})
```

Or even as pure [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) without the use of [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) which you only need in MongoDB where multiple conditions would be applied to the same field. Otherwise [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) is implicit to all arguments:

```
db.collection.find({ "category": /^\s+|\s+$/ })
```

Which restricts the matched documents to process to only those with leading or trailing white-space.

If you are worried about the number of documents to look, bulk updating should help if you have MongoDB 2.6 or greater available:

```
var batch = [];
db.collection.find({ "category": /^\s+|\s+$/ },{ "category": 1 }).forEach(
    function(doc) {
        batch.push({
            "q": { "_id": doc._id },
            "u": { "$set": { "category": doc.catetgory.trim() } }
        });

        if ( batch.length % 1000 == 0 ) {
            db.runCommand("update", batch);
            batch = [];
        }
    }
);

if ( batch.length > 0 )
    db.runCommand("update", batch);
```

Or even with the [bulk operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp/) for MongoDB 2.6 and above:

```
var counter = 0;
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
db.collection.find({ "category": /^\s+|\s+$/ },{ "category": 1}).forEach(
    function(doc) {
        bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).update({
            "$set": { "category": doc.category.trim() }
        });
        counter = counter + 1;

        if ( counter % 1000 == 0 ) {
            bulk.execute();
            bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        }
    }
);

if ( counter > 1 )
    bulk.execute();
```

**Best** done with `bulkWrite()` for modern API's which uses the Bulk Operations API ( technically *everything* does now ) but actually in a way that is *safely regressive* with older versions of MongoDB. Though in all honesty that would mean prior to MongoDB 2.6 and you would be well out of coverage for official support options using such a version. The coding is somewhat cleaner for this:

```
var batch = [];
db.collection.find({ "category": /^\s+|\s+$/ },{ "category": 1}).forEach(
  function(doc) {
    batch.push({
      "updateOne": {
        "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
        "update": { "$set": { "category": doc.category.trim() } }
      }
    });

    if ( batch.length % 1000 == 0 ) {
      db.collection.bulkWrite(batch);
      batch = [];
    }
  }
);

if ( batch.length > 0 ) {
  db.collection.bulkWrite(batch);
  batch = [];
}
```

Which all only send operations to the server **once** per 1000 documents, or as many modifications as you can fit under the 64MB BSON limit.

As just a few ways to approach the problem. Or update your CSV file first before importing.

Answer (score 20):

- Starting `Mongo 4.2`, [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) can accept an aggregation pipeline, finally allowing the update of a field based on its own value.
- Starting `Mongo 4.0`, the [`$trim`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/index.html) operator can be applied on a string to remove its leading/trailing white spaces:

```javascript
// { category: "Financial & Legal Services " }
// { category: " IT  " }
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [{ $set: { category: { $trim: { input: "$category" } } } }]
)
// { category: "Financial & Legal Services" }
// { category: "IT" }
```

Note that:

- The first part `{}` is the match query, filtering which documents to update (in this case all documents).
- The second part `[{ $set: { category: { $trim: { input: "$category" } } } }]` is the update aggregation pipeline (note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline):

  - [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator which in this case replaces the value for `"category"`.
  - With [`$trim`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/index.html) we modify and trim the value for `"category"`.
  - Note that `$trim` can take an optional parameter `chars` which allows specifying which characters to trim.

Comment: Mongo 6.0 onwards `db.collection.update` is deprecated. So use this instead
`db.collection.updateMany({}, [{ $set: { category: { $trim: { input: "$category" } } } }])`

Comment: Creates object for me MongoDb 5.0.5

Answer (score 8):

Small correction to the answer from Neil for bulk operations api

it is

```
initializeOrderedBulkOp
```

not

```
initializeBulkOrderedOp
```

also you missed to

```
counter++;
```

inside the forEach, so in summary

```js
var counter = 1;
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
db.collection.find({ "category": /^\s+|\s+$/ },{ "category": 1}).forEach(
    function(doc) {
        bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).update({
            "$set": { "category": doc.category.trim() }
        });

        if ( counter % 1000 == 0 ) {
            bulk.execute();
            counter = 1;
        }
        counter++;
    }
);

if ( counter > 1 )
    bulk.execute();
```

Note: I don't have enough reputation to comment, hence adding an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can execute javascript in an MongoDB update command when it's in a cursor method:

```
db.collection.find({},{ "category": 1 }).forEach(function(doc) {
  db.collection.update(
    { "_id": doc._id },
    { "$set": { "category": doc.category.trim() } }
  );
})
```

If you have a ton of records and need to batch process, you might want to look at the other answers here.

Comment: It's basically same as the first part of the accepted answer, but I like this one because it is a little shorter. Thanks.