# mongodb aggregate on datetime keys

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My document consists of `login_time` and `logout_time`, and I set aggregate on it such as below:

```js
 db.connection_log.aggregate([{'$match':{"logout_time" : "2014-05-12 05:45:19"}},
{'$group': {'_id': {'ras_id': '$ras_id'},'total':  
{'$sum':{'$subtract':["$ISODate(logout_time)","$ISODate(login_time)"]}}}])
```

My data on document:

```js
{'_id': ObjectId('5370982f1abbf80c21a3dd51'),
 '_type': 1,
 'caller_id': '',
 'credit_used': 0,
 'details': {'ip_assignment': false,
             'kill_reason': 'Killed by admin system',
             'mac': '',
             'persistent_lan': true,
             'user_id': NumberLong(805)},
 'login_time': '2014-05-12 05:44:37',
 'logout_time': '2014-05-12 05:45:19',
 'ras_id': 1,
 'retry_count': 1,
 'successful': true,
 'type_details': {'in_bytes': 0, 'out_bytes': 0, 'remote_ip': '10.0.0.1/32'},
 'unique_id': 'remote_ip',
 'unique_id_value': '10.0.0.1/32',
 'user_id': NumberLong(805),
 'username': 'ali'}
```

But it doesn't work for me.
How to sum on my dates filed?
please help me.

Comment: Those look like strings to me. You need to convert these to proper date types first. And fix the code that is inserting them as strings.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem you have here is that your "dates" are actually strings. You need them to be date types instead. So scripting to fix, in JavaScript shell form:

```js
db.connection_log.find({},{ "login_time": 1, "logout_time": 1}).forEach(
    function(doc) {
        db.connection_log.update(
            { "_id": doc._id },
            {
                "$set": { 
                    "login_time": new ISODate( doc["login_time"] ),
                    "logout_time": new ISODate( doc["logout_time"] )
                }
            }
        );
    }
)
```

Then you can actually aggregate properly:

```js
db.connection_log.aggregate([
    { "$match":{ "logout_time" : ISODate("2014-05-12 05:45:19") }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$ras_id",
        "total": { 
            "$sum":{
                "$subtract":[
                    "$logout_time",
                    "$login_time"
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

So that will actually give you a result abstracted  as an epoch timestamp value difference of  the "milliseconds" between the times. Which is an integer you can [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

Also see [**this recent answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23903988/2313887) for efficient ways to update your collection.

Comment: very thanks.
can I update my field such alter command in sql?

Comment: @user3676300 As the other answer I gave that was referenced essentially says, there is no present way in MongoDB to refer to the existing value of a field when performing an update. The exception is operators like **`$inc`** but all that does in increment a value. You need to `.find()` and modify. Read that answer, there is some good information in there. Others clearly thought so from the up-votes :)

Comment: @user3676300 You also have a correct aggregation statement here aside from good advice on how to correct your existing data. Most would find that exceedingly helpful :) Good luck with your endeavors.

Comment: @user3676300 Sorry for the flood of comments, but this is also an important one. The "ALTER" command of SQL you refer to is a DDL statement designed to modify "Schema". MongoDB is "Schema-less" so there is no concept of "this field contains a `Date` type, from a "schema modification" point of view. You actually need to change the "type" of data that is stored there as there is no way to "alter schema" such as more well behaved SQL engines will do

Comment: @user3676300 You can actually thank by accepting the answer given, which is the the nice way to do things here :)