# Trim values of records / delete spaces/tabs

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, trim

Here is an example of my MongoDb structure :

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "status" : "     fsdfsdf           "
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "status" : "        ffdfg       "
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 4,
            "status" : "   fsdfsdfsdfdsf          "
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to make a query update.. the query must trim (delete spaces, and/or tabs)
So my records will be :

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "theText" : "fsdfsdf"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "status" : "ffdfg"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 4,
            "status" : "fsdfsdfsdfdsf"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB removing white spaces(leading and trailing) from string value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903785/mongodb-removing-white-spacesleading-and-trailing-from-string-value)

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB does not provide a string operator to trim our string out of the box but we can build one using the Aggregation Framework however this solution requires MongoDB 3.4 or newer.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
        "children": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$children", 
                "as": "child", 
                "in": { 
                    "id": "$$child.id", 
                    "status": {
                        "$arrayElemAt": [
                            { "$filter": { 
                                "input": { "$split": [ "$$child.status", " " ] },
                                "as": "ch", 
                                "cond": { "$gt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$$ch" }, 0 ]}
                            }}, 
                            0
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$out": "coll" }
])
```

We only need one stage in our pipeline which is the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/$project) stage or the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields) stage. I choose to use `$addFields` to automatically include other fields in the result.

We need to apply an expression to each element in the "children" array which is a perfect job for the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map) array operator.

In the *in* expression, we simply [`$split`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split) our string in sub-strings, [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter) the resulted array by removing all the sub-string which length is **0**.

To return the length of a string we use the [`$strLenCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/) operator.

We then return the only remaining string using the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt) operator.

The last stage in our pipeline is the [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/$out) stage where you write the result to a new collection or replace the old collection.

---

Another alternative is using `mapReduce` to [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the *space* and update your collection using bulk operations:

### MapReduce query:

```
db.coll.mapReduce(function() { 
    emit(
        this._id, 
        this.children.map( child => { 
            return { "id": child.id, "status": child.status.trim() };
        })
    ); }, function(key, value) {}, {"out": {"inline": 1 }}
)
```

**The update section is left as an exercise to the reader**.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write some client side javascript. In the mongo shell you can do:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function (doc){
  for (subDoc of doc.children) {
    if(typeof subDoc.theText === 'string') {
      subDoc.theText = subDoc.theText.trim();
    }
    if(typeof subDoc.status === 'string') {
      subDoc.status = subDoc.status.trim();
    }
  }
  db.collection.save(doc);
})
```

Comment: I had :  E QUERY    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
I did  db.getCollection('myCollectionNAME').find .....

Comment: Fixed typos. And yes, `db.getCollection('myCollectionNAME')` will work too.

Comment: how to fix typos ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to trim all your `children.status` fields by executing a javascript `forEach` loop over the document array on the MongoDB cursor:

```js
db.COLLECTION_NAME.find({}).forEach(
  function(doc){
    db.COLLECTION_NAME.update({"_id":doc.id}, {"$set":{
      children:doc.children.map(function(child){return Object.assign(
        child,
        {
          status: child.status.trim()        
        }
      )})
    }})
  }
)
```

Of course you'll need to update COLLECTION_NAME and any other relevant fields. You may also want to add some logic to ensure that the values are of the type you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`$trim`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/) aggregation in mongodb **4.0** and [**`$out`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) aggregation to throw out to the new collection.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "children": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$children",
        "in": {
          "id": "$$this.id",
          "status": { "$trim": { "input": "$$this.status" }}
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$out": "collection_name" }
])
```