# Trim string values of whitespace, from an array of sub-documents with string field

Tags: mongodb

On all documents of my collection I want to perform a `$trim` operation to a specific field of an object that is in an array.

Example:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53857680f7b2eb611e843a32"),
  "company": Testcompany
  "customer" :
      "name": Testuser,
      "addresses" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d2f96e3fdc8001077ac6c"), 
                "street" : "Teststreet.   ", 
                "houseNr" : "133", 
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5d6d2f96e3fdc8001077ac7b"), 
                "street" : "    Simplestreet.   ", 
                "houseNr" : "12", 
            }
        ], 
}
```

In the example, I want to `$trim` all values of the field: `"customer.addresses.street"`

To answer the upcoming questions:

1. I know the article you mentioned ([Removing white spaces (leading and trailing) from string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903785/removing-white-spaces-leading-and-trailing-from-string-value)) but theres no example how to do it within an array.

My problem is, how to access the attributes within an array, heres the example of plain values:

[{ $set: { category: { $trim: { input: "$category" } } } }],

2. Yes, I want to update the values of all documents within the collection

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any issues you are facing? Here is post with similar question and answer: [Remove whitespace (leading and trailing) from string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903785/removing-white-spaces-leading-and-trailing-from-string-value). _Also_, you can search the net with a search-string like _"mongodb trim spaces from field"_ for more answers.

Comment: Do you want to update the document _or_ just get an output with the trimmed field values?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do:

```
db.YOUR_COLLECTION.find({}).forEach(
    function(doc) {
        db.Trim.update(
            { "_id":doc._id }, 
            { 
                "$set": {
                    "customer.addresses":doc.customer.addresses.map(
                        function(child) {
                            return Object.assign(
                                child,
                                { street: child.street.trim() }
                            )
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Obs: Solution with Javascript Executed in MongoShell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $map and $trim in an updateMany aggregation pipeline like this :

```
db.YOUR_COLLECTION.updateMany({"customer.addresses":{$ne:null}},[
     {
            $set: {
                "customer.addresses":
                { 
                   $map: {
                          input: "$customer.addresses",
                          as: "address",
                          in: { $trim: { input: "$$address" } }
                        }
                 }
            }
    }
])
```