# How to make trim() function work in node.js code, even if not used in mongoose's model schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've a mongodb collection which stores "Customers" data. I need to trim the mobile number of a customer if there are any trailing or leading white spaces available. I've used `trim()` function to remove them. But am getting an error, **trim() is not a function**.

Here's my model schema:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    name    : {type: String, required: true},
    email   : {type: String, required: true},
    mobile  : {type: String, required: true, index: false, unique: false});

module.exports = mongoose.model("customer", schema);
```

Here's the code where I've used trim function:

```
addNewCustomer: async function(payload){
  var customer = new Customer({
     name  : payload.name,
     email : payload.email,
     mobile: payload.mobile.trim()
  });
}
```

When I execute the above function, it is giving me the error. 
But if I use `trim()` at schema level, it is working fine.

```
mobile  : {type: String, required: true, index: false, unique: false, trim: true});
```

What is the difference between using trim() in SCHEMA level and FUNCTIONALITY level? Why it is not working when used in function?

Comment: What error it gives when you are using `trim()` in function ?

Comment: ```trim() is not a function```

Comment: If you `console.log(typeof payload.mobile)` in the function what do you get?

Comment: please debug the type of typeof(payload.mobile)

Comment: I'll test it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have seen functional alternative 'cursor' syntax ala:

```
db.collection.find({},{ "category": 1 }).forEach(function(doc) {
  db.collection.update(
    { "_id": doc._id },
    { "$set": { "category": doc.category.trim() } }
  );
})
```

Above example copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554968/2003321